# In PHP, how do I reliably transfer binary data as 'body' of an HTTP response?

Tags: php, http, binary-data

When I compare

- sample_data.png that I trasferred as the body of my http response with
- /tmp/downloaded.png that got downloaded by my download.php

I find the following difference

```
% cmp sample_data.png /tmp/downloaded.png
/tmp/downloaded.png sample_data.png differ: char 1, line 1
```

looks like the contents are very much the same
except for the first two newline characters I see in my downloaded file.

What I am missing?
I understand there are many other ways of transferring files --
but I am particularly interested in transferring arbitrary binary data
as the body of a http request/response and receiving that http-body-content reliably from the client side.

**fileupload.php**

```php
<?php        
        
$file = 'sample_data.png';        
    
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    $fch = fopen($file, 'r');
    print fread($fch, filesize($file));
    flush();
    $fclose($fch);
    exit;
}

?>
```

**download.php**

```php
<?php

$ch = curl_init ( "http://localhost/fileupload.php" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CRLF,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$resp = curl_exec ( $ch );

if ( $resp ) {
    $len = strlen($resp);
    echo "received string of length $len\n";
    $handle = fopen('/tmp/downloaded.png','w');
    fwrite($handle, $resp);
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "no response";
}

?>
```

Comment: Make sure that your PHP file doesn't output anything except the content of your file.... ne echo/print statements; nothing between `?>` and `<?php`, no BOM header.... it's why a lot of libraries don't ever use a closing `?>` anywhere

Comment: fileupload.php

    <?php  -- that is most likely the issue.

Comment: that was the issue. I did not realize that the spaces preceding the <?php gets to be part of the body of the http response.